# Exporting selected layouts in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts, parameters, attributeerror

I would like to export selected layouts from an ArcGIS project. The error I keep receiving is

> AttributeError: ValueObject: Get attribute exportToPDF does not exist

Is there something different about the list of layouts when it is inputted as a parameter with the "GetParameter" function vs when listing all layers in the project with the ".listLayers()" function?

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
figFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
layouts = arcpy.GetParameter(1)

for lyt in layouts:
    lyt.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + lyt.name + ".pdf",
                    resolution=100,
                    jpeg_compression_quality=20)
    lyt.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + lyt.name + "_HighRes.pdf",
                    resolution=300,
                    jpeg_compression_quality=100)
```

Parameter Setup:
[image: Parameter Setup]

Comment: What is returned when you print the variable named `layouts`?  I suspect it's a string when it needs to be a list of Layout objects for the rest of your code to work.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro calls it a 'list' object.

Comment: The list appears to be a list of names of the layouts in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you set your second script parameter to be of type `Layout` when you wired up the interface to your script, it appears for a Layout a [Geoprocessing Value object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/value.htm) is returned, not a layout object. Why? No idea!

The page in the help file confirms that GetParameter() can return a Value Object depending on the parameter type. So returning a Value object, to get the value you use `.value` which according to the help file returns a string. So your code needs to adapt to this:

```py
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
figFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
ValueObj= arcpy.GetParameter(1) # The parameter was set to Layout
layoutname = ValueObj.value # Returns a string, the name of the layout
layout = aprx.listLayouts(layoutname)[0] # Get a handle on layout object

# Do exports
layout.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + layoutname + ".pdf", resolution=100, jpeg_compression_quality=20)
layout.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + layoutname  + "_HighRes.pdf", resolution=300, jpeg_compression_quality=100)
```

If you have set your script interface to take **multiple values** of Layouts then Parameter 1 will return a list of value objects. To process such a list the code would be:

```py
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
figFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
lstValueObj= arcpy.GetParameter(1) # The parameter was set to Multiple Values of Layout so it returns a list
for vo in lstValueObj:
    layoutname = vo.value # Returns a string, the name of the layout
    layout = aprx.listLayouts(layoutname)[0] # Get a handle on layout object

    # Do exports
    arcpy.AddMessage("Processing layout: " + layoutname)
    layout.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + layoutname + ".pdf", resolution=100, jpeg_compression_quality=20)
    layout.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + layoutname  + "_HighRes.pdf", resolution=300, jpeg_compression_quality=100)
```

Comment: Interesting about the Geoprocessing Value object. I did set the parameter up as a `Layout` type, and also `Multiple values`. I tried to run your code but it gave me the error that `layoutname = ValueObj.value # Returns a string, the name of the layout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: @ThomasQuintero - Please see additional edits for dealing with multiple values.

Comment: Works great as well, thanks @Hornbydd !

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with help from the [answer by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/407926/115).

```
    import arcpy
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

    '''Parameters'''
    figFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # The parameter is set to Folder
    layout_names = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # The parameter is set to Layout

    all_layouts = aprx.listLayouts()
    selected_layouts = []

    # Loop through the names of the layouts and if the name matches,
    # copy to selected_layouts
    for nm in all_layouts:
         if nm.name in layout_names:
             selected_layouts.append(nm)
         else:
              pass

    #Exporting PDF low and high resolution
    for lyt in selected_layouts:
        lyt.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + lyt.name + ".pdf",
                        resolution=100,
                        jpeg_compression_quality=20)
        lyt.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + lyt.name + "_HighRes.pdf",
                        resolution=300,
                        jpeg_compression_quality=100)
```